# Getting null when using TextSelection sel = (TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vspackage

I created a Visual Studio 2013 plugin that uses this line of code for example:

```
public void CodeElementFromPointExample(DTE2 dte)
{
    try
    {
        TextSelection sel =
           (TextSelection) dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;

        TextPoint pnt = (TextPoint)sel.ActivePoint;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm getting a null exception in the line :

```
TextSelection sel = (TextSelection) dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;
```

In general, I would like to discover a "cs" file code and to find a method name where I click on the file and its attributes for example.

Comment: Selection is, as the name suggest, the currently selected text in the document. Just clicking somewhere does not select anything.

Comment: I do not just click somewhere on the document, i select a text and then click copy, then then Copy event invokes and inside this method i try to do the rest, discover the the method etc.

Comment: Do you have n example how to do it correct?, i don't find a real working example in the web. just snippets codes.

Comment: Maybe your dte variable is null?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, either dte or dte.ActiveDocument can be null. Use some code logic to determine the case.

Once you get that dte.ActiveDocument is not null, get its .Object property and try to cast it to EnvDTE.TextDocument, to see if the active document is a text document.

Then, TextDocument.Selection returns a TextSelection object.